# How to group list of countries to continents in R?

Tags: r

i try to group given list of data (single countries) to a list of continents.
this did not work:

```
df = read.csv("~/Datasampling/02/datos_pwt10_continents.csv")

tfr_recoded <- df:group_by(testplot = fct_collapse(Country,
      "Europe" = c("Italy", "Spain", "Portugal", "Estonia","Denmark","Iceland","Finland","Norway","Sweden", "Bulgaria", "Belarus", "Poland", "Lithuania", "Hungary", "Ukraine", "Germany","United Kingdom", "France", "Switzerland", "Austria","Netherlands","Czechia", "Slovenia", "Slovakia", "Croatia"),
      "Asia" = c("Taiwan", "Republic of Korea", "Japan"),
      "America" = c("USA", "Chile", "Canada")))
```

[List Data provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFAf6.png)

Comment: Error in df:library(dplyr) : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In df:library(dplyr) :
  numerical expression has 20 elements: only the first used
2: NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 0):

If we change the syntax error, it should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df %>% 
   group_by(test_plot = fct_collapse(country,  
     "Europe" = c("Italy", "Spain", "Portugal", "Estonia","Denmark","Iceland",
  "Finland","Norway","Sweden", "Bulgaria", "Belarus", "Poland", 
    "Lithuania", "Hungary", "Ukraine", "Germany","United Kingdom", 
    "France", "Switzerland", "Austria","Netherlands","Czechia", 
  "Slovenia", "Slovakia", "Croatia"),  
       "Asia" = c("Taiwan", "Republic of Korea", "Japan"),   
     "America" = c("USA", "Chile", "Canada")))
```

Comment: Sorry ;/ now i get following error: Error in `group_by()`:
! Problem adding computed columns.
Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `test_plot = fct_collapse(...)`.
Caused by error in `check_factor()`:
! object 'country' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @Ramona the error says you don't don't have a column named 'Country'.  Can you show the `names(df)`

Comment: @Ramona maybe you had a lowercase 'country', try the update

Comment: it is right in lower case > names(df) 
[1] "country.isocode.year.currency.rgdpe.rgdpo.pop.emp.avh.hc.ccon.cda.cgdpe.cgdpo.cn.ck.ctfp.cwtfp.rgdpna.rconna.rdana.rnna.rkna.rtfpna.rwtfpna.labsh.irr.delta.xr.pl_con.pl_da.pl_gdpo.i_cig.i_xm.i_xr.i_outlier.i_irr.cor_exp.statcap.csh_c.csh_i.csh_g.csh_x.csh_m.csh_r.pl_c.pl_i.pl_g.pl_x.pl_m.pl_n.pl_k.Continent_Name.Continent_Code"

Comment: @Ramona Maybe you haven't read the data correctly. i.e. you may have to correctly specify the delimiter if it is not comma separated

Comment: i just saw "Continent_Code" :O hm... maybe using that instead of the country labels?

Comment: @Ramona Can you show the `dput(head(df))`